# Mapping JSON Response to Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, mapping

New to the notion of Rails mapping, and would love to get some help on this from the stack overflow community.

Currently I have this JSON response from the Embedly API and don't really know how to map it to my very simple 'posts' model. I'm trying to get the **image/title/url** from the JSON response and map it into my database in the relevant fields, so in the JSON response below these would be 'original_url', 'image' and 'title'.

```
{
    "provider_url": "http://piccsy.com", 
    "authors": [], 
    "provider_display": "piccsy.com", 
    "related": [], 
    "favicon_url": "http://piccsy.com/favicon.ico", 
    "keywords": [], 
    "app_links": [], 
    "original_url": "http://piccsy.com/2015/02/rihanna-sharks-harpers-bazaar-march-2015-photoshoot3", 
    "media": {}, 
    "content": null, 
    "entities": [], 
    "provider_name": "Piccsy", 
    "type": "html", 
    "description": "Beautiful, inspirational and creative images from Piccsy. Thousands of Piccs from all our streams, for you to browse, enjoy and share with a friend.", 
    "embeds": [], 
    "images": [
        {
            "width": 728, 
            "url": "http://img2.piccsy.com/cache/images/56/8f/bed__396d8_cecf850824130_99f-post.jpg", 
            "height": 1092, 
            "caption": null, 
            "colors": [
                {
                    "color": [
                        190, 
                        211, 
                        212
                    ], 
                    "weight": 0.3095703125
                }, 
                {
                    "color": [
                        114, 
                        159, 
                        171
                    ], 
                    "weight": 0.247314453125
                }, 
                {
                    "color": [
                        0, 
                        52, 
                        68
                    ], 
                    "weight": 0.244140625
                }, 
                {
                    "color": [
                        25, 
                        99, 
                        117
                    ], 
                    "weight": 0.198974609375
                }
            ], 
            "entropy": 5.94797179868, 
            "size": 318918
        }, 
        {
            "width": 200, 
            "url": "http://piccsy.com/piccsy/images/layout/logo/e02f43.200x200.jpg", 
            "height": 200, 
            "caption": null, 
            "colors": [
                {
                    "color": [
                        215, 
                        51, 
                        67
                    ], 
                    "weight": 0.701904296875
                }, 
                {
                    "color": [
                        250, 
                        252, 
                        252
                    ], 
                    "weight": 0.298095703125
                }
            ], 
            "entropy": 0.686638083774, 
            "size": 18691
        }
    ], 
    "safe": true, 
    "offset": null, 
    "cache_age": 86065, 
    "lead": null, 
    "language": null, 
    "url": "http://piccsy.com/2015/02/rihanna-sharks-harpers-bazaar-march-2015-photoshoot3", 
    "title": "Rihanna-sharks-harpers-bazaar-march-2015-photoshoot3", 
    "favicon_colors": [
        {
            "color": [
                208, 
                37, 
                38
            ], 
            "weight": 0.000244140625
        }, 
        {
            "color": [
                0, 
                0, 
                0
            ], 
            "weight": 0.000244140625
        }
    ], 
    "published": null
}
```

My posts model contains very simple name, url and image fields which are all accepting strings. Any help on mapping this to a model would be brilliant, up till now I've only done very simple JSON responses and this one is a bit out of my league.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just parse json response, and get required fields from it

```
json_response = '{your json response from api}'
response_hash = JSON.parse(json_response)
MyModel.create!(url: response_hash[:original_url], title: response_hash[:title])
```

But there is problem with images, response contains multiple images, so probably you should have ImageModel that belongs to MyModel, and MyModel has_many ImageModels.

Then you can do:

```
model = MyModel.create!(url: response_hash[:original_url], title: response_hash[:title])
response_hash[:images].each do |image|
  model.images.create!(url: image[:url])
end
```